# Pass query string to Page Viewer Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have a share point page, in which I have added a page viewer web part. This web part needs to be supplied with a query string in addition with the static URL.

I tried putting a QueryString Filter Web Part but it did let me connect with the page viewer web part(Message - *the connection type send parameter values is not compatible with any web part on the page*)

I was wondering whats the correct way to achieve this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got going...
The solution is to create your own visual web part. Visual web part is not but a user control which a web part loads in in CreateChildControl method.

Now you have access to code behind, Sharepoint Context, you can do what ever you want.

[How to create Visual Web Part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413295%28v=office.14%29.aspx)